# Ansible Tower - set_facts varaiable shows empty value

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I have some strange issue where the playbook works well on Ansible Engine but no on Ansible Tower:

- Ansible: 2.9.7
- Ansible Tower: 3.6.4
- Python: 2.7 (virtual env)

**Playbooks**

```yaml
- name: "{{ dns_server_name }} - Add to Summary"
  set_fact:
    dns_verification_summary_final: |
      {{ 
        dns_verification_summary_final 
        | combine({
            dns_server_name: {
              'dns_server_name': dns_server_name,
              'dns_server_ip'  : dns_server_ip,
              'success_count'  : dns_a_counter_pass,
              'failed_count'   : dns_a_counter_fail,
              'failed_hosts'   : dns_a_check_failed_entries
            }
          }) 
      }}
  
- name: "{{ dns_server_name }} - Check Summary"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ dns_verification_summary_final }}"
```

**Ansible Engine** - Working Fine

```
TASK [dns-verification : dns2 - Add to Summary] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [dns-verification : dns2 - Check Summary] ************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "dns2": {
            "dns_server_ip": "8.8.8.8", 
            "dns_server_name": "dns2", 
            "failed_count": "2", 
            "failed_hosts": [
                "twitter.com", 
                "facebook.com"
            ], 
            "success_count": "1"
        }, 
        "dns3": {
            "dns_server_ip": "8.8.4.4", 
            "dns_server_name": "dns3", 
            "failed_count": "2", 
            "failed_hosts": [
                "twitter.com", 
                "facebook.com"
            ], 
            "success_count": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

**Ansible Tower** -

The task output says the variable set as `ansible_facts`.

```json
ok: [localhost] => {
  "ansible_facts": {
    "dns_verification_summary_final": {
      "xxx": {
        "dns_server_name": "yyy",
        "failed_count": "3",
        "failed_hosts": {
          "blockthisurl01.net",
          "blockthisurl02.net",
          "blockthisurl03.net"
        },
        "success_count": 0
      }
    },
    "myvar": "zzz"
  },
  "changed": false
}
```

But the debug message prints an empty variable.

```json
ok: [localhost] => {
  "msg": []
}
```

Comment: remove images from the question and put text showing the same.

Comment: Sorry, those screenshots are from remote desktop and unable to copy text due to restriction. This playbooks is running against akamai virtual appliance and difficult to simulate at lab !

I will try to replace with text anyway.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not a answer but the solution for my problem listed above.

The issue was with the variable (but no idea how !!!); I have used different variable name and it was working. Same issue happened for another variable as well and I renamed the variable and it worked !!!

Anyway, the issue has been closed; I will try to find more details if possible.

Thank you.